# Angular - how to receive nested error message object back from rest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

Seems that this current code that I have is NOT able to show me the return of the web api data

**Angular $http.post**

```
  return $http.post(`${calparkUrl}/api/request`, 
                  data, 
                    {calApiResponse: true});
```

With **Postman** I see this error

```
  {
    "data": null,
    "hasErrors": true,
    "errorList": [
     "This Order cannot be submitted as entered. A combination of this information is already in use."
     ]
  }
```

What do I NEED to add to my $http.post in order to retrieve that `hasErrors` and `errorList` ??

**Update**

Will the following ever even display the console.log for either response or the error?   I want to be able to TELL the caller ( code calling this and expecting the return )  whether the data is good or bad ... etc

```
 return $http.post(`${calibrusSparkUrl}/api/request`, data).
           then (function successCallback(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
           }).
            errorCallback(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
           });
```

Comment: What is the status code when REST API returns that error? Status codes inside the range 200-299 go to the success handler, codes outside the range go  to the rejection handler. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage).

Comment: @georgeawg   -  I posted another question and I would greatly appreciate your feedback on the persons answer to me , along with possible better answer from you    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362821/angular-callbacks-and-promises-the-data-flow-needs-to-stop-if-haserrors-is-tru