# Angular Promises and Chaining: How to break a chain if it has business data errors

Tags: angularjs, promise, http-post, angular-promise

I thought that I had this all figured out on previous projects through the years.. Apparently not.

Goal :  Take Service that calls other Services and if there is any type of error being returned  ( <del>not a status of 200</del> )  then I need the async thing to be waiting and not proceeding.

Seems to me like I don't ever see really that great of examples as it is all very simplistic.

I read various articles about what Angular (1) is doing under the hood , and i see that there are  $q,  .then,  .success  etc..

Seems that I am having issues with `return` and with other nested and bundled service calls being made without any checking of a problem.

Essentially this image shows what is coming back

data : null   ( that is bad) 
errorList  Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmdBd.png)  0   "This order cannot be submitted... "    ( bad too) 
hasErrors : true   ( bad as well)

So that data is important to me to capture and display to user and then NOT move onto more processing

[image]

**This is my order of operations**

```
this.submitEnrollment = function (enrollment) {
    return getSubmit(requestData);
}

// Which CALLS below

var getSubmit = function (request) {
    return SparkRequestService
        .submitRequest(request)
        .then(
            function (resData) {
                console.log("resData", resData);
                enrollmentService.resetEnrollment();
                return resData;
            }, 
            function (resData) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        );
}
```

Then I'm certainly calling `SparkRequestService.submitRequest(request)`
but based on the image attached,  I am getting the error in the `resData`

So, it seems that I need to interrogate the `resData` right?  So then I really should NOT ALLOW this other service to be called  `enrollmentService.resetEnrollment();`

How can i refactor to stop from that getting processed?   if statement in the `.then`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a rejection handler from **converting** a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise it is important use a `throw` statement in the rejection handler:

```
var getSubmit = function (request) {
    return SparkRequestService
        .submitRequest(request)
        .then(
            function (resData) {
                console.log("resData", resData);
                enrollmentService.resetEnrollment();
                return resData;
            }, 
            function (errorResponse) {
                console.log('error');
                //IMPORTANT
                //throw to chain rejection
                throw errorResponse;
            }
        );
}
```

When a function omits a `return` or `throw` statement, the function returns a value of `undefined`. This will **convert** a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise that resolves with a value of `undefined`.

---

> Problem is that ... it is a business error wrapped up in a return object

To **convert** a fulfilled promise to a rejected promise, use a `throw` statement.

```
this.submitEnrollment = function (enrollment) {
    var promise = getSubmit(requestData);
    var newPromise = promise.then(function(response) {
         if (response.data.hasErrors) {
             console.log(response.data.errorList);
             response.data.errorList.push("submitEnrollent: Rejected"); 
             //THROW to create rejection
             throw response;
         } else {
             //RETURN response to chain success
             return response;
         }
    });
    return newPromise;
}
```

When a promise is **converted** to a rejection, all subsequent success handlers in the chain will be skipped. The chain will be followed until a rejection handler is found.

Comment: Problem is that `enrollmentService.resetEnrollment();`  is going to get called because technically it is a business error wrapped up in a return object so I don't see how the `function(errorResponse)` will even get hit  ,

Comment: The part of the question that confused me is that it said **"not a status of 200**" when in fact you were seeking to reject a status 200 (OK) http response under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the promise returned by `SparkRequestService.submitRequest(request)` is not *rejected* when you get the error inside `resData`. For this reason the *successCallback* of `then` is invoked and not the second one, the *errorCallback*.

For this reason, inside the *successCallback* you need to inspect the data of `resData` to check errors and behave accordingly, for example:

```
var getSubmit = function (request) {
    return SparkRequestService
        .submitRequest(request)
        .then(function (resData) {
                console.log("resData", resData);
                if(resData === null) { // Check for errors
                    // There is an error, manage it inside this block of code
                    // ...
                    // You can also create a rejected promise with $q.reject() and passing resData containing the errors
                    return $q.reject(resData);
                } else {
                    // Call resetEnrollment() in the ELSE branch so, it is executed only if resData does not contain errors
                    enrollmentService.resetEnrollment();
                    return resData;
                }
            }, 
            function (resData) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the advise   resData is never null though ,  I will give you a +1 as you helped me a lot in the right direction  -  thx