# Unit Test Does Not resolve deferred promise on digest/apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

### Service

```js
angular.module('App').service('producerContactSvc', ['$http', 'configSvc', function($http, configSvc) {

  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $http.defaults.headers.common = {};

  var _this = this;

  _this.getProducerContacts = function(producerId) {
    var endpoint = configSvc.backendUrl + '/producerContact/read?producerId=' + producerId;
    return $http.get(endpoint)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  _this.addProducerContact = function(producerContact) {
    var endpoint = configSvc.backendUrl + '/producerContact/create';
    return $http.post(endpoint, producerContact)
      .success(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  _this.deleteProducerContact = function(producerContactId, producerId) {
    var endpoint = configSvc.backendUrl + '/producerContact/delete?producerContactId=' + producerContactId + '&' + 'producerId=' + producerId;
    return $http.delete(endpoint)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  _this.updateProducerContact = function(producerContact) {
    var endpoint = configSvc.backendUrl + '/producerContact/update';
    return $http.put(endpoint, producerContact)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

}]);
```

### Controller

```js
angular.module('App').controller('producerAdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'producerSvc', '$mdDialog', 'producerContactSvc', 'errorToastSvc', function($scope, $rootScope, producerSvc, $mdDialog, producerContactSvc, errorToastSvc) {
      $scope.results = false;
      $scope.producerTypeCodes = ['CX', 'FG'];
      $scope.producerId = null;
      $scope.documents = [];
      $scope.selectedDocs = [];

      $scope.producerContactRows = [];
      $scope.missingName = false;
      $scope.producerContactTypeCodes = ['MC', 'BC'];

      /**
       * Get a list of all producers on load
       */
      producerSvc.getAllProducers()
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response !== null) {

            $scope.unusedProducers = response.data;
          } else {
            $scope.noFound = true;
            $scope.results = false;
            $scope.message = 'No Data Received';
          }
        });

      /**
       * Perform a search on a producer. This will call the backend and find information about the producer searched for
       */
      $scope.search = function() {
        $scope.documents = [];
        $scope.selectedDocs = [];
        $scope.query = $scope.selectedItem.producerId;
        producerSvc.getProducer($scope.query).then(function(response) {
          if (response && response.data) {
            $scope.producer = response.data;
            $scope.producerId = $scope.query;
            $scope.producer.inactiveDate = response.data.inactiveDate === null ? null : new Date(response.data.inactiveDate);
            producerSvc.getAllDocs().then(function(response) {
              _.forEach(response, function(doc) {
                var docObject = {
                  documentId: doc.documentId,
                  documentDescription: doc.documentDescription,
                  documentName: doc.documentName,
                  selected: false
                };
                $scope.documents.push(docObject);
              });

              producerSvc.getProducerDocs($scope.producerId).then(function(response2) {
                _.forEach(response2.data, function(docProducer) {
                  var docId = docProducer.documentId;
                  _.forEach($scope.documents, function(doc) {
                    if (docId === doc.documentId) {
                      doc.selected = true;
                      $scope.selectedDocs.push(doc);
                    }
                  });
                });

                $scope.documents.sort(function(x, y) {
                  return (x.selected === y.selected) ? 0 : x.selected ? -1 : 1;
                });

                $scope.results = true;
                $scope.noFound = false;

              });

            });
          } else {
            $scope.noFound = true;
            $scope.results = false;
            $scope.message = 'No Producer Found';
          }
        });

        producerContactSvc.getProducerContacts($scope.query).then(function(response) {
          _.forEach(response, function(producerContact) {
            var producerContactObject = {
              producerContactName: producerContact.producerContactName,
              editable: false,
              producerContactEmail: producerContact.producerContactEmail,
              producerContactType: producerContact.producerContactType,
              invalid: false,
              producerContactIsNew: false,
              producerContactId: producerContact.producerContactId,
              producerId: producerContact.producerId
            };
            $scope.producerContactRows.push(producerContactObject);
          });
        });

        /**
         * Add a new producerContact to the producerContactRows array.
         */
        $scope.addProducerContact = function() {
          var producerId = '';
          var producerContactName = '';
          var producerContactEmail = '';
          var producerContactType = '';
          var producerContactObject = {
            producerId: producerId,
            producerContactName: producerContactName,
            editable: true,
            producerContactEmail: producerContactEmail,
            producerContactType: producerContactType,
            invalid: false,
            producerContactIsNew: true
          };
          $scope.producerContactRows.push(producerContactObject);
        };

        /**
         * Enable edit mode on a selected producerContact.
         * @param {number} producerContactIndex the index within the producerContactRows array of the producerContact to edit.
         */
        $scope.editProducerContact = function(producerContactIndex) {
          $scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].editable = true;
        };

        /**
         * Save a selected producerContact.
         * @param {number} producerContactIndex the index within the producerContactRows array of the producerContact to save.
         */

        $scope.saveProducerContact = function(producerContactIndex) {
          if ($scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].producerContactIsNew) {
            producerContactSvc.addProducerContact($scope.sanitizeProducerContact($scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex])).then(function(response) {
              $scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].producerContactId = response.data.producerContactId;
            });

            $scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].producerContactIsNew = false;
          } else {
            producerContactSvc.updateProducerContact($scope.sanitizeProducerContact($scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex]));
          }

          $scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].editable = false;
        };

        /**
         * Prompt the user for confirmation they want to delete a producerContact.
         * @param {number} producerContactIndex the index within the producerContactRows array of the producerContact to delete.
         */
        $scope.deleteProducerContact = function(producerContactIndex, ev) {
          var deleteProducerContact = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Are you sure you want to delete this ProducerContact?')
            .ariaLabel('Delete ProducerContact')
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .ok('Delete ProducerContact')
            .cancel('Cancel');
          $mdDialog.show(deleteProducerContact).then(function() {
            $scope.performDelete(producerContactIndex);
          });
        };

        /**
         * Delete a selected producerContact after verification.
         * @param {number} producerContactIndex the index within the producerContactRows array of the producerContact to delete.
         */
        $scope.performDelete = function(producerContactIndex) {
          console.log($scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex]);
          if (!$scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].producerContactIsNew) {
            producerContactSvc.deleteProducerContact($scope.producerContactRows[producerContactIndex].producerContactId, $scope.producerId);
          }

          $scope.producerContactRows.splice(producerContactIndex, 1);
        };


        /**
         * Save the producer information to the backend
         */
        $scope.saveProducer = function() {
          var docObjects = [];
          var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
          var user = null;

          if ($rootScope.apmHeader) {
            user = $rootScope.apmHeader.userI;
          }

          _.forEach($scope.selectedDocs, function(doc) {
            var docObject = {
              documentid: doc.documentId,
              producerId: $scope.producerId,
              approvedby: user,
              dateapproved: timestamp
            };
            docObjects.push(docObject);
          });

          $scope.producer.documentList = docObjects;
          producerSvc.saveProducerInfo($scope.producer);
        };
      }]);
```

### Test Class

```js
describe('Test Producer Contact', function() {
  //Add an initialize here:
  var $scope;
  var $rootScope;
  var controller;

  // deferred variables
  var getProducerDefer;
  var getProducerContactsDefer;
  var addProducerContactDefer;
  var updateProducerContactDefer;
  var deleteProducerContactDefer;

  var producerContactSvc;

  var mockProducerContacts = [{
      producerContactId: '11111',
      producerId: '1111',
      producerContactName: 'abcd',
      producerContactEmail: 'abcd@abc.com',
      producerContactType: 'cc',
      editable: false,
      invalid: false,
      producerContactIsNew: false
    },
    {
      producerContactId: '11112',
      producerId: '1111',
      producerContactName: 'efgh',
      producerContactEmail: 'efgh@xyc.com',
      producerContactType: 'primary',
      editable: false,
      invalid: false,
      producerContactIsNew: false
    },
    {
      producerContactId: '12345',
      producerId: '1111',
      producerContactName: 'asdh',
      producerContactEmail: 'asdh@xyc.com',
      producerContactType: 'cc',
      editable: false,
      invalid: false,
      producerContactIsNew: false
    }
  ];

  beforeEach(module('FirstSaleApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, producerSvc, producerContactSvc, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    producerContactSvc.deleteProducerContact = function() {
      return null;
    };

    // We use the $q service to create a mock instance of defer
    getProducerDefer = _$q_.defer();
    getProducerContactsDefer = _$q_.defer();
    addProducerContactDefer = _$q_.defer();
    updateProducerContactDefer = _$q_.defer();
    deleteProducerContactDefer = _$q_.defer();

    // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
    spyOn(producerSvc, 'getAllProducers').and.returnValue(getProducerDefer.promise);
    spyOn(producerContactSvc, 'getProducerContacts').and.returnValue(getProducerContactsDefer.promise);
    spyOn(producerContactSvc, 'addProducerContact').and.returnValue(addProducerContactDefer.promise);
    spyOn(producerContactSvc, 'updateProducerContact').and.returnValue(updateProducerContactDefer.promise);
    spyOn(producerContactSvc, 'deleteProducerContact').and.returnValue(deleteProducerContactDefer.promise);

    $controller('producerAdminCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      producerSvc: producerSvc,
      producerContactSvc: producerContactSvc
    });

    // getProducerDefer.resolve(mockProducers);
    getProducerContactsDefer.resolve(mockProducerContacts);
    //  $scope.$digest();
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));

  it('controller exists', function() {
    expect(controller).not.toBeNull();
  });

  it('should get the producerContacts from the producerContact service', function() {

    // $scope.producerContactRows = $scope.getProducerContacts(1111);

    // The length should match
    expect($scope.producerContactRows.length).toBe(3); // <-- coming as 0

    // The values should be the same too
    // Mock 1
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[0].producerContactName).toBe(mockProducerContacts[0].producerContactName);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[0].producerContactEmail).toBe(mockProducerContacts[0].producerContactEmail);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[0].producerContactType).toBe(mockProducerContacts[0].producerContactType);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[0].editable).toBeFalsy();
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[0].producerContactIsNew).toBeFalsy();

    // Mock 2
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[1].producerContactName).toBe(mockProducerContacts[1].producerContactName);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[1].producerContactEmail).toBe(mockProducerContacts[1].producerContactEmail);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[1].producerContactType).toBe(mockProducerContacts[1].producerContactType);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[1].editable).toBeFalsy();
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[1].producerContactIsNew).toBeFalsy();

    // Mock 3
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[2].producerContactName).toBe(mockProducerContacts[2].producerContactName);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[2].producerContactEmail).toBe(mockProducerContacts[2].producerContactEmail);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[2].producerContactType).toBe(mockProducerContacts[2].producerContactType);
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[2].editable).toBeFalsy();
    expect($scope.producerContactRows[2].producerContactIsNew).toBeFalsy();

  });
});
```

I'm new to angularjs - I have started working on an app that uses karma and jasmine to test. I am trying to use deferred promise to stub a method call. However I don't see the data after I digest (or apply) the scope. Any help is appreciated on what I might be missing. Thanks

Comment: The example is too lng to follow (and suffers from fat controller). But it is not clear where ...contactRows is supposed to be changed. It is set to empty array in controller constructor.

Comment: Agree about the fat controller - and the ...rows is changed in the controller - look for the line $scope.producerContactRows.push(producerContactObject);
However I think the problem I'm facing is the spy is not getting invoked!
I want this getProducerContactsDefer.resolve(mockProducerContacts);
to call the invoke the spy and populate the rows.

Comment: Don't use the `.success` method. Also why does the code convert rejected promises to fulfilled promises?

Comment: **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Comment: @user2666282 It is called in `search` method. You're not calling it.

Comment: @estus thx - so where do I call it and how?

Comment: @georgeawg thx - can you show me a code example that does what you are saying?

Comment: In tests. With $scope.search(). Currently you're testing a function that isn't called anywhere. It won't call itself.

Comment: See [StackOverflow: Angular Promises and Chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362821/angular-promises-and-chaining-how-to-break-a-chain-if-it-has-business-data-erro/42374249#42374249) for an example of code that erroneously **converts** rejected promises to fulfilled promises.

Comment: @estus ok - so put    
$scope.search();
$scope.$digest();
In all the tests  (that access methods under search) ? 
Or do I put the .search only? (and put digest at the inject level?)

Comment: It depends on the situation. $digest() serves for practical reason, it's not a ritual. search contains promises. And promises are fired by digests. So $digest() should be called after search. And btw, $rootScope.$digest() and $scope.$digest() are totally different things. Don't use $scope.$digest() unless you know that this one should be used.

Comment: Now I put these two lines in the 2nd test - 
$scope.search(); $rootScope.$digest();
And I get:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.selectedItem.producerId')
Also isn't the digest call mandatory as this will resolve the promise:
getProducerContactsDefer.resolve(mockProducerContacts);